# Single content from array without brackets - python

Tags: python, arrays

i need help. I tried almost everything.
I have an two-dimensional array like `superarray[][]` in Python.

What i need to do is save an content of current field in array in variable. When Im doing it it's always with brackets. I tried almost everything (for cycle, join...)

What my code looks like:

```
for i in range (0,3)
 myVariable = superarray[i][0]
```

I tried this

```
myVariable = "{}".format(str(superarray[i][0]))
```

and this

```
myVariable = "".join(superarray[i][0]
```

and a few other things.

I'd like to say I'm not PRO in python, actually I started a month ago, but I'm coding pretty nice things for big data mining, but I can not solve this.
Please help me, thank you.

Comment: Can you give a sample of the `superarray` ?!

Comment: Can you specify what is the input that you are giving and what should be the expected output?

Comment: could you just print `superarray` (perhaps using the pretty print module, or just directly) and show us a snippet of the output?

Comment: Superarray looks like this:   `[['EKOFAN corp.','We are super corporation',' for your bussiness'], ['Incorporated investment','How great are we?','SuperGreat Blah blah']]` Outpout should be like "EKOFAN corp.". And if I would like to have second part of first field in array it should look like - "We are super corporation".   Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing was working for me, so I had to use this code:
       for j in range(0,len(superarray)):
         for z in range(0,3):
            superarray[j][z] = superarray[j][z].replace("['","")
            superarray[j][z] = superarray[j][z].replace("']","")

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
myVariable = ''
for i in range (0,3):
    myVariable += str(superarray[i][0])
```

**UPDATE**

Taking the example you posted in the comment above you should simply do:

```
superarray = [['EKOFAN corp.','We are super corporation',' for your bussiness'], ['Incorporated investment','How great are we?','SuperGreat Blah blah']]
myVariable = superarray[0][0]
print myVariable
```

Comment: if i use (str) infront of  variable, nothing happens. Result is is with brackets :/